# How to call ngOnit function of a component from another component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, ngoninit

I have a component called "**CreateBugsViewComponent**" in this component I wat to use **ngOnit** function of my another component which is "**ProjectBugsComponent**" how can I do this the code for "**CreateBugsViewComponent**" is written below:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-createbugview',
  templateUrl: './createbugview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createbugview.component.scss']
})
export class CreatebugviewComponent implements OnInit {
    onbugsubmit(){
    if(this.createbugform.valid)
    {
      this.createbugform.controls['BugsAttachments'].setValue(this.images);
      this.http.post(this.baseURI+'Bugs/Addbug',this.createbugform.value).subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
          //this.changeLocation(),
          this.snackbar.open(data.message,'✖', {
            duration:4000,
            horizontalPosition:'center',
            verticalPosition:'top'
          }),
          //this.dialog.closeAll(),
          localStorage.removeItem('ProjectId')/////////////////In this function I want to use ngOnit of  ProjectBugsComponent Component.
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

If there is any other information anyone wants then let me know in the comments I will provide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the shared logic in a service and inject the service in the components.

**Shared service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedLogicService {
  sharedFunction(router): void {
    console.log(router.routerState.snapshot.url, 'called')
  }
}
```

**ComponentA** or **ComponentB**

```
constructor(private router: Router, private sharedLogicService: SharedLogicService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedLogicService.sharedFunction(this.router);
}
```

Comment: can you show me how can I do this shared logic service????

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you ask is actually a **bad practice**.
And the shortest solution with that bad practice would be:

1. Create a static public method in `ProjectBugsComponent` (let's say we call it `uglyMethod()`)
2. Move out the logic of `ngOnInit` of `ProjectBugsComponent` to `uglyMethod()`
3. From `CreateBugsViewComponent` import the `ProjectBugsComponent` and call
   `ProjectBugsComponent.uglyMethod()`

This would solve the problem, but again, what you ask is a bad practice.
In general, the **best practice** would be creating a service, moving out that common logic from `ngOnInit` to there, and calling it from both components whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to follow [this article](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to approach the communication between the components. Angular already has the described approaches and this one is not in the list. But if you really want, here is an example:

**app-layout.component.ts**

```
import { StudentsComponent } from './../students/students.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './app-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-layout.component.scss']
})
export class AppLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private studentsC: StudentsComponent) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // calling NgOnInit in StudentComponent
    this.studentsC.ngOnInit()
  }

}
```

**students.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.scss']
})
//**!!! important to add**
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url, 'called')
  }

}
```

Comment: but it will lead me to angular circular dependency which is not good for my code.

Comment: This is still not working and showing an Angular dependency warning......